# List products from nested categories

Tags: php, mysql

I work hierarchical categories and products table for my project.

categories table structure:

**ID - PARENT - TITLE**

1  -  0     - Computer

1  -  0     - Phones

...

Categories table count of row 25107.

Product Table structure

**ID - CAT - TITLE**

1 - 1 - Product Name is here

I want current category and sub categories  for list product.

```
echo $subcats = categoryChild(0);
```

Output is: 64198,18355,18356,95623,90504,6118,90505,6117,90506,90507,6119,6120,90508,90509,90510,90511,6103,90512,90513,90514,90515,142686,142688,142790,90516,6105,90517,90518,90519,90520,90521,91691,91692,92189,92190,92312,92313,95618,95619,95620,95621,95622,142684,142690,142692,142694,142696,142698,142700,3596

And I'm using this output MySQL IN statment.
Finally generate this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat IN (64198,18355,18356,95623,90504,6118,90505,6117,90506,90507,6119,6120,90508,90509,90510,90511,6103,90512,90513,90514,90515,142686,142688,142790,90516,6105,90517,90518,90519,90520,90521,91691,91692,92189,92190,92312,92313,95618,95619,95620,95621,95622,142684,142690,142692,142694,142696,142698,142700,3596)
```

This query is very slow... Please help me.

Comment: A really basic check, but have you indexed the "cat" field ;-)?

Comment: How do you get $subcats = categoryChild(0) ?

Comment: categoryChild is generate catagory id from parentId. 0 is parent id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
select p.id as id, p.title as title, c.title as category, c.id as catid
from products p JOIN
(select * from category where id = 1 OR parent = 1) c
on p.cat = c.id
```

see how it works on [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e397/7)

to list all hierarchy levels, write a code like this:

```
// return all childs of category with id $cat
function list_childs($cat){
    // run above query and change (select * from category where id = 1 OR parent = 1)
    // to (select * from category where parent = $cat) and return results
}
```

then in your code call this function for every category where you want to get children's

Comment: How can I using one more sub category id? because your sql code only id and parent id. im using hierical category

Comment: your category hierarchy limited? or you want to get child in all level of hierarchy?

Comment: i want to get child all level of hierarchy.

Comment: Farnabaz, have you got a idea? because your solution partially run for me.

Comment: to get all hierarchy level, write a function `listChilds($cat)` to list the next level of child's and call function recursively for child's

Comment: Thank you! How is it performance? I think the slow run. And this solution only get list child. How is it list product

Answer (score 0):

use this will allow you to fetch cat and sub cat for the parent_id argument.
its nested and can be style with css and html.

`

```
     <ul class="" id="">

<?php
   function query($parent_id, $extension = null) { //function to run a query
   $query = mysql_query ( "SELECT * FROM exe_categories WHERE parent_id=$parent_id");
   return $query;
}
   function has_child($query) { //This function checks if the menus has childs or not
   $rows = mysql_num_rows ( $query );
   if ($rows > 0) {
    return true;
   } else {
    return false;
   }
}
function fetch_menu($query) {
   while ( $result = mysql_fetch_array ( $query ) ) {
     $id = $result ['id'];
     $title = $result ['title'];
     $menu_link = $result ['menu_link'];
     echo "<li><a href='{$menu_link}'><span>{$title}</span></a>";

        if (has_child ( query ( $id ) )) {
                    echo "<div>";
                    echo '<ul role="menu" class="fofc">';

                    fetch_menu ( query ( $id ) );
                    echo "</ul>";
                    echo "</div>";
        }

             echo "</li>";
      }
 }
   fetch_menu (query(1)); //call this function with 1 parent id

 ?>`
```